# SQL with ambiguous column

Tags: sql, oracle

Check the following example (Oracle syntax):

```
create table t1 (id number, a varchar2(255));
create table t2 (id number, a varchar2(255));
create table t3 (id number);

select * from t1 where id in (select id from t2 where a = 'aa');
select * from t1 where id in (select id from t3 where a = 'aa');
```

Both select work fine but they use different attributes for filtering. In my opinion first SQL should give an error because column a is ambiguously defined. Is this not defined in the official SQL standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't the clearest statement, but [the documentation does refer to this behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm):

> If columns in a subquery have the same name as columns in the containing statement, then you must prefix any reference to the column of the table from the containing statement with the table name or alias. To make your statements easier to read, always qualify the columns in a subquery with the name or alias of the table, view, or materialized view.

So essentially that's saying that for your first statement to reference `t1.a` you would have to explicitly use it's name (or alias):

```
select * from t1 where id in (select id from t2 where t1.a = 'aa');
```

If you don't then it will use the subquery's table by default. It isn't ambiguous to the parser because it will look at the tables in the same level of (sub)query first, and only look at the outer level if it can't find that column in the current level. That might not be what you're expecting, and I agree complaining that it is ambiguous would be better to avoid subtle mistakes that give wrong results; but it is how it works.

But as it also says, it's safer to always be explicit anyway:

```
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select t2.id from t2 where t2.a = 'aa');
```

or

```
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select t2.id from t2 where t1.a = 'aa');
```

and for your second statement:

```
select * from t1 where t1.id in (select t3.id from t3 where t1.a = 'aa');
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what we have in our coding conventions. But sometimes end users do not stick to them ;-) So we tried top remove some legacy attributes while the statements kept executing but completely did the wrong thing because it took the other attribute. So we where wondering if there shouldn't be an error in the first place?

Comment: @Whisky_jb - I agree an error would make sense here, but that's not what Oracle decided to do, for whatever reason. This behaviour probably goes back to its very early days, and I'm not aware of any way to change it.

Comment: @AlexPoole: that behaviour is what the SQL standard requires. Oracle followed the standard here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - interesting, if slightly surprising. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is exactly what it should be, based on long-standing principles of programming. I haven't seen the SQL standard (apparently it can't be inspected for free), but in programming in general the "collision" between names is one of the most common issues, and at least for some situations there are very simple rules. This is one of them: a local name will always mask the same name that may exist in the calling environment.

The sad thing is, Oracle itself doesn't always follow this simple rule. There are some bugs related to this in factored subqueries (there has been some discussion of this on OTN, resulting in filing bug reports with Oracle).

Comment: Yes, and we opened also an SR for this example but they just close it as they say its OK. In my opinion ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined should appear to make users aware of the issue? But maybe I'm just wrong?

Comment: What I meant is, with a WITH clause Oracle doesn't always look for local variables first (they don't always mask the same name from the calling environment). Your example is clearly not a bug, since the behavior is intentional and documented - see Alex's answer.

Answer (score -1):

The first SQL.

```
select * from t1 where id in (select id from t2 where a = 'aa');
```

The first query will take `t2` table's `"a"` column while executing the query. As we know that both the tables `t1` and `t2` have same column name but the preferences given to local column.

Second SQL.

```
select * from t1 where id in (select id from t3 where a = 'aa');
```

While executing the second query it will select column `"a"` from table `t1`.

Because there is not any column named "a" and hence the SQL will take different attribute to execute the query.

Comment: I'm not repeating, i'm just explaining.